# Do SVG files automatically compress to their smallest possible pixel size based on their attributes?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, pixel, automatic-properties

I'm working on a bit of code that generates graphs in SVG, and I want to know what the size of the generated SVG file will be. For, instance, for the following set of two lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="400.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="400.0" x2="600.0" y2="400.0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

The generated image will automatically be 600 by 400 pixels, correct? Or is there a separate definition I have to make?

Comment: No, 601 by 401 pixels.

Comment: Actually 601 units by 601 units. The SVG will be the size of the container.